# Javascript for autotab input text by maxlength and checking array

Tags: javascript

I tried to implement function but it does not work.  The autotab works by itself , but as soon as I check whether the input value is a member of an array then it won't autotab anymore.

```
function check()
{
var listing = [100,101,102];
var letters = document.myinput.one.value.length +1;
if (letters <= 3) {
  document.myinput.one.focus()
}
else {
  if (listing.indexOf(document.myinput.one.value) >= 0){
    document.myinput.two.focus()
  }
  else {document.myinput.one.focus()
  }
}

<FORM NAME="myinput">
<INPUT TYPE="text" name="one" size="4" MAXLENGTH="3" onKeyUp="check()"><BR>
<INPUT TYPE="text" name="two" size="10" MAXLENGTH="3"><BR>
</FORM>
```

If I omit the :

```
 if (listing.indexOf(document.myinput.one.value) >= 0)
```

part then it will change focus to input two.  Any idea why it won't work?  I use Chrome only as it is part of browser based app.

Comment: Unrelated: `document.myinput.one` is not standard. You should use `document.forms.myinput.elements.one`

Comment: noted and change it in my code, but it still won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because document.myinput.one.value return a string, and your array contain integers. use parseInt()

```
 function check()
    {
    var listing = [100,101,102];
    var letters = document.myinput.one.value.length +1;
    if (letters <= 3) {
      document.myinput.one.focus()
    }
    else {
      if (listing.indexOf(parseInt(document.myinput.one.value)) >= 0){
        document.myinput.two.focus()
      }
      else {
    document.myinput.one.focus()
      }
    }
    }
```

Comment: still not working, I have tried to change the listing array to string also as listing = ["100", "101", "102"].  Also have tried listing = "100 101 102"

Comment: function check()
    {
    var listing = [100,101,102];
    var letters = document.myinput.one.value.length +1;
console.log(letters);
    if (letters <= 3) {
console.log("case 1");
      document.myinput.one.focus()
    }
    else {
console.log(listing, document.myinput.one.value, listing.indexOf(parseInt(document.myinput.one.value));


      if (listing.indexOf(parseInt(document.myinput.one.value)) >= 0){
console.log("case 2");
        document.myinput.two.focus()
      }
      else {
console.log("case 3");
    document.myinput.one.focus()
      }
    }
    }

Comment: and also, Oriol said that this:
Unrelated: document.myinput.one is not standard. You should use document.forms.myinput.elements.one

ps I test my previos function in goolge chrome browser. It work fine there.

pps better select elements using their classname, or identifiers.

Comment: Well, seems that something wrong here.  It won't work in my google browser.  I have tried 2 computers and both of your functions.  Any idea why?  I put on jsfiddle also can't run?

Comment: OK, I change the indexof to < -1 and it work in aviator.  But I tried again in the jsfiddle, and the same piece of code (I copy paste from the working one) still don't run.  I am puzzled!  Anyway I update jsfiddle to the version that now work in my browser.

Comment: in jsfiddle: Uncaught ReferenceError: check is not defined

Comment: Sorry, should be >=-1.  Anyway it also works in chrome, Thanks!